# Sending requests with buffer when service down

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have feign service:

```
    @FeignClient(url = "email-service")
    public interface EmailFeign {
        @RequestMapping(method = POST, path = "/")
        void postEmail(@RequestBody Email email);

        @RequestMapping(method = PUT, path = "/")
        void putEmail(@RequestBody Email email);
    }
```

Requirements:

1. No need to wait for the method execute (async).
2. When email-service is down it is required to save all mails and send them after enabling email-service.
3. Email-service is considered down after the first unsuccessful
   attempt to send mail.
4. If email-service is down is required to check email-service each
   DELAY seconds.
5. It is allowed to send messages in one thread but it is preferable to
   send messages in several threads.

I resolved it with BlockingDeque and DemonThread:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    wait();
                }
            }
            Runnable poll = queue.poll();
            if (!tryRun(poll)) {
                queue.addFirst(poll);
                //I use notify when queue is not empty so I can't use wait() in this case
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

I want to find smarter solution. Perhaps with one of the ServiceExecutor implementations.

Thanks.

Edit:
One more solution

```
public class PausableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final long delay;

    private volatile boolean isPaused = false;
    private ReentrantLock pauseLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition unpaused = pauseLock.newCondition();

    public PausableThreadPoolExecutor(long delay, int threadCount) {
        super(1, threadCount, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
        pauseLock.lock();
        pauseLock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        //If exception has occurred
        if (t != null) {
            isPaused = true;
            pauseLock.lock();
            // Double Checked Locking
            if (isPaused) {
                try {
                    unpaused.await(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error("Pause error", e);
                } finally {
                    isPaused = false;
                    pauseLock.unlock();
                }
            }
            execute(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider using a message broker such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ.

Comment: It is a good solution but unfortunately I can't change API of email-service at this moment.